# Collision check of a 6-DOF robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm

Initially we started with 3-DOF. We checked collisions in the c-space and it worked well. With 6-DOF we're having problems.
Any ideas about how to check collisions for a 6-DOF robotic arm?

--Edit
I'm going to clarify my needs. I have a algorithm based on a hybrid architecture (PRM + Q learning) that plan trajectories.
As some of you now, when building the roadmap using a PRM algorithm, you need to sample configurations (series of 6 angles for a 6R 6DOF robot in my case as we are working in the configuration space). You have to check if these configurations lead to a collision or not. If not you add them to the roadmap.
My problem is with the part where i need to check if a configuration leads to a collision.
At first, when we were testing for a 3R 3DOF robot, we had a brute-force method that worked pretty well but i'm not going into the details here unless some of you are interested.
This method didn't work for a 6R robot for many reasons.
What i need is a check-collision function that takes into account the kinematics of my robot and the environment in order to calculate if a configuration leads to a collision or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a vague question, but from what you provided I would suggest:

- Check **how** you are defining your C-Space. Do redundant configurations perform different collision checking?
- Take a look at the [Flexible Collision Library - FCL](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl) . Maybe their framework guides you towards a proper arrangement of your overall joint system.
- Check the [Open Motion Planning Library - OMPL](https://ompl.kavrakilab.org/) . Combined with the FCL, you should be able to end up with a proper collision checking system for your arm.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

## solution

The arm should stop on Resistence(Torque increase) or detected Impact. Build the arm to be soft.

## Alternative solution

Otherwise the Software can Check if the angle are close to the folddown position and stop moving further.